# Automatically including any number of CSV file as a resource in a WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible for me to automatically include any number of CSV files in any number of folders by including the parent folder in the csproj file like this?

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="ParentFolder\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If this is possible, how would I reference all of these resources? The CSV files all have shared names in child folders. Could I just give the file path like using a file normally? I do not want to include the files in the output directory for security reasons and want them wrapped in the build executable file.

Comment: *security reasons* hehehehe ... [and that's it about "security"](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy)

Comment: If you need security, better encrypt the files and/or store them remotely. Or even drop the plain text .csv file type and go with a database. Compiling text files into a DLL or executable is not safe at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. You can add an entry like this to your `*.csproj` file, which recursively references the `testfiles` folder on project level:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="..\testfiles\**\*">
      <Link>testfiles\%(RecursiveDir)/%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Resource>
</ItemGroup>
```

Also have a look at [this blog post](https://mazeez.dev/posts/csproj-include-folders-recursively), which shows basically the same but includes the file not as resource.

Comment: He wana to include them as Resource

Comment: Right, thanks @Selvin - I've updated my answer.

Comment: How do I reference the resources?

Comment: They are already referenced if included like this.

Comment: Prolly it's working only with "sdk type" projects